# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string error while converting hex to decimal

Tags: java, hex, decimal, decimalformat

When i run this code it gives NumberFormatException? how do i convert A49D43C5 this numbers to decimal in java?

```
logger.info("Decimal value: " + Integer.parseInt("A49D43C5", 16));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is larger than an `int` ([`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) is 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 or `2147483647`). You could use a `long` like

```
System.out.println("Decimal value: " + Long.parseLong("A49D43C5", 16));
```

Output is

```
Decimal value: 2761769925
```

Answer (score 0):

`Integer`'s max value is **2147483647**.

try to use `BigInteger` for your hexadecimal.

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hexString, 16);
```